# How to make a list parameter optional in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have the following configuration

```
abc:
  - vm_name: "abc"
    template:
      cate: Apple
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - geen
      - blue
  - vm_name: "xyz"
    template:
      cate: Orange
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - blue
      - yellow
      - black
```

and to group the vms into groups I use the code

```
locals {

  cfg_vars = yamldecode(file("test1.yaml"))
  list_color = flatten(local.config_vars["abc"][*]["cat"])

  
  inventory_map = merge([for color in local.list_color: {
    for vm in local.cfg_vars["abc"]:
      color => vm.vm_name... if contains(vm.cat, color)
      } 
  ]...)
}
```

The code works fine and I get the following list in `local.inventory_map` for above configuration.

```
{     
  "black" = [
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "blue" = [
    "abc",  
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "geen" = [  
    "abc",    
  ]        
  "red" = [   
    "abc",               
    "xyz",               
  ]           
  "yellow" = [           
    "xyz",               
  ]                      
}
```

However, I want the parameter `cat` to be optional. But if I give a vm with no `cat` parameter, then nothing happens. I want it to work for the following configuration too

```
abc:
  - vm_name: "abc"
    template:
      cate: Apple
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - geen
      - blue
  - vm_name: "xyz"
    template:
      cate: Orange
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
    cat:
      - red
      - blue
      - yellow
      - black
  - vm_name: "efg"
    template:
      cate: Orange
      image: "ubuntu18"
    cpu_cores: 1
    memory: 1024
```

As you can see, no `cat` parameter is defined in the third VM `efg`. In such case I want to get the same inventory file as above because the third vm is not using cat i.e.

```
{     
  "black" = [
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "blue" = [
    "abc",  
    "xyz",  
  ]         
  "geen" = [  
    "abc",    
  ]        
  "red" = [   
    "abc",               
    "xyz",               
  ]           
  "yellow" = [           
    "xyz",               
  ]                      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `lookup` to the code to check for `cat`. If `cat` is not present, then you get empty list instead:

```
locals {
  cfg_vars = yamldecode(file("test1.yaml"))
  list_color = distinct(flatten(
         [for vm in local.cfg_vars["abc"][*]: lookup(vm, "cat", [])]
      ))
  
  inventory_map = merge([for color in local.list_color: {
    for vm in local.cfg_vars["abc"]:
      color => vm.vm_name... if contains(lookup(vm, "cat", []), color)
      } 
  ]...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver. I was thinking a similar answer but since `list_color` is a list I was looking for `index` function as the net says lookup is to search map but you knows better I think. Another question is if `lookup` cant find `cat` and put an empty list then will it not make the existing data of the two vms empty too?

Comment: @Dr.Mian The code should produce exactly what you want. Did you run it?

Comment: Trying.........

Comment: You are the boss, spot on again! checking a couple of more scenarios before accepting the answer :)